# Keinen Und Keinen vs Oder

Tags: word-choice

A resource I am using to learn German says that to say

> She does not like tea or coffee

would translate to

> *Sie mag keinen Tee und keinen Kaffee*.

Why would this be the case, instead of saying:

> *Sie mag keinen Tee oder Kaffee.*

Is my resource wrong?

Comment: Your English example is wrong. English speakers say: *She likes neither tea nor coffee.* They don't use "or" in that construction.

Comment: "She does not like tea or coffee" is perfectly good English. (Native speaker here.)

Comment: My friend, I am a native speaker of the English language. Born and raised in Texas, trust me "She does not like tea or coffee" is not wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) at work: `not (a or b) == (not a) and (not b)`

German *nicht* and even more *kein* binds closely to the very next item. That's why we prefer to say

> Sie mag keinen Tee und keinen Kaffee.

instead of

> Sie mag keinen *Tee oder Kaffee*.

Both are possible, but the latter is often expressed as

> Sie mag weder Tee noch Kaffee.

You may add more options:

> Sie mag weder Tee noch Kaffee noch Wasser.
>
> Sie mag weder Tee noch Kaffee, weder Wasser noch Limo.

Comment: Added remark: the "weder ... noch" equals the English "neither ... nor" and is indeed, as Janka said, the normal way to negate multiple options in German.